# java XStream: how 2 process collections between jdks?

Tags: java, collections, hashmap, xstream

I have a httpSession generated in ibm jdk(IBM-Java60-amd64) and parsed to a xml using XStream.
I want to recreate this session map on other jdk (orecle-jdk1.6.0-x86), but an error occurs on deserialization.

My Xstream object:

```
public static XStream getXStreamConfigured( ){

 final XStream xstream = new XStream(){

  @Override
  protected MapperWrapper wrapMapper( final MapperWrapper next ){

    return new MapperWrapper( next )
    {

      @Override
      public boolean shouldSerializeMember(
           final Class definedIn,
           final String fieldName ){

         if ( definedIn == Object.class ){
            return false;
         }

         return super.shouldSerializeMember( definedIn, fieldName );
      }

    };      
  }

};

 xstream.autodetectAnnotations( true );

 final String dateFormatXmlPattern = FundXmlHandler.DATE_FORMAT_VIEW_AND_XML_FORMAT;
 final DateConverter dateConverter = new XStreamConverterDate( dateFormatXmlPattern );
 xstream.registerConverter( dateConverter );

 return xstream;
```

}

using the oracle jdk, some tags generated in this output xml is like:

```
<java.util.TreeMap_-KeySet>
  <m class="tree-map"/>
</java.util.TreeMap_-KeySet>
```

using the ibm jdk, some tags generated in this output xml is like:

```
<java.util.TreeMap_-1>
    <outer_class/>
</java.util.TreeMap_-1>
```

Why it generate this for TreeMaps?
Why i cant load the xml generated by ibm jdk in oracle jdk?
How can i writte a converter that generate the same output in both jdk?

My stack:

```
---- Debugging information ----
message             : java.util.TreeMap$1
cause-exception     : com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.CannotResolveClassException
cause-message       : java.util.TreeMap$1
class               : java.util.HashMap
required-type       : java.util.HashMap
converter-type      : com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.collections.MapConverter
path                : /map/entry[92]/java.util.TreeMap$1
line number         : 161079
version             : null
-------------------------------
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.TreeUnmarshaller.convert(TreeUnmarshaller.java:79)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.AbstractReferenceUnmarshaller.convert(AbstractReferenceUnmarshaller.java:65)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.TreeUnmarshaller.convertAnother(TreeUnmarshaller.java:66)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.TreeUnmarshaller.convertAnother(TreeUnmarshaller.java:50)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.TreeUnmarshaller.start(TreeUnmarshaller.java:134)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.AbstractTreeMarshallingStrategy.unmarshal(AbstractTreeMarshallingStrategy.java:32)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.XStream.unmarshal(XStream.java:1052)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.XStream.unmarshal(XStream.java:1036)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.XStream.fromXML(XStream.java:912)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.XStream.fromXML(XStream.java:903)
    at br.com.mindsatwork.vinci.rwf.util.UtilitiesRwf.loadSavedSessionObject(UtilitiesRwf.java:3222)
    at br.com.mindsatwork.vinci.rwf.util.UtilitiesRwf.getFundDataFromSavedSession(UtilitiesRwf.java:1912)
    at br.com.mindsatwork.vinci.rwf.web.action.ActionHandleSavedSession.getFundData(ActionHandleSavedSession.java:86)
    at br.com.mindsatwork.vinci.rwf.web.action.AbstractActionWithFundDataUpload.executeIfLogged(AbstractActionWithFundDataUpload.java:88)
    at br.com.mindsatwork.vinci.rwf.web.action.ActionHandleSavedSession.executeIfLogged(ActionHandleSavedSession.java:64)
    at br.com.mindsatwork.vinci.rwf.web.action.AbstractActionWithLogin.executeAction(AbstractActionWithLogin.java:80)
    at br.com.mindsatwork.vinci.rwf.web.action.AbstractVinciAction.executeAction(AbstractVinciAction.java:148)
    at br.com.utilities.servlet.struts.action.AbstractStrutsActionWithDynaForm.executeAction(AbstractStrutsActionWithDynaForm.java:75)
    at br.com.utilities.servlet.struts.action.AbstractStrutsAction.execute(AbstractStrutsAction.java:57)
    at org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.processActionPerform(RequestProcessor.java:476)
    at org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.process(RequestProcessor.java:239)
    at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.process(ActionServlet.java:1334)
    at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.doGet(ActionServlet.java:426)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:621)
    at br.com.utilities.servlet.struts.AbstractStrutsAppServer.service(AbstractStrutsAppServer.java:344)
    at br.com.mindsatwork.vinci.rwf.web.AppServer.service(AppServer.java:303)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:304)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:240)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:164)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:576)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:164)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:100)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:563)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:399)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11AprProcessor.process(Http11AprProcessor.java:306)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11AprProtocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11AprProtocol.java:322)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(AprEndpoint.java:1732)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
Caused by: com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.CannotResolveClassException: java.util.TreeMap$1
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.DefaultMapper.realClass(DefaultMapper.java:56)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.MapperWrapper.realClass(MapperWrapper.java:30)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.DynamicProxyMapper.realClass(DynamicProxyMapper.java:55)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.MapperWrapper.realClass(MapperWrapper.java:30)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.PackageAliasingMapper.realClass(PackageAliasingMapper.java:88)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.MapperWrapper.realClass(MapperWrapper.java:30)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.ClassAliasingMapper.realClass(ClassAliasingMapper.java:79)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.MapperWrapper.realClass(MapperWrapper.java:30)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.MapperWrapper.realClass(MapperWrapper.java:30)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.MapperWrapper.realClass(MapperWrapper.java:30)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.MapperWrapper.realClass(MapperWrapper.java:30)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.MapperWrapper.realClass(MapperWrapper.java:30)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.MapperWrapper.realClass(MapperWrapper.java:30)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.ArrayMapper.realClass(ArrayMapper.java:74)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.MapperWrapper.realClass(MapperWrapper.java:30)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.MapperWrapper.realClass(MapperWrapper.java:30)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.MapperWrapper.realClass(MapperWrapper.java:30)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.MapperWrapper.realClass(MapperWrapper.java:30)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.MapperWrapper.realClass(MapperWrapper.java:30)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.MapperWrapper.realClass(MapperWrapper.java:30)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.MapperWrapper.realClass(MapperWrapper.java:30)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.CachingMapper.realClass(CachingMapper.java:45)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.util.HierarchicalStreams.readClassType(HierarchicalStreams.java:29)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.collections.AbstractCollectionConverter.readItem(AbstractCollectionConverter.java:70)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.collections.MapConverter.putCurrentEntryIntoMap(MapConverter.java:89)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.collections.MapConverter.populateMap(MapConverter.java:77)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.collections.MapConverter.populateMap(MapConverter.java:71)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.collections.MapConverter.unmarshal(MapConverter.java:66)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.TreeUnmarshaller.convert(TreeUnmarshaller.java:72)
    ... 42 more
```

How can i write a generic collections types into this output xml, that can be assembled into different jdks?

The link http://x-stream.github.io/faq.html shows that XStream has two operation modes, the Pure Java and Enhanced (default). The Pure Java supposedly works with various JVMs. 
I tried to instantiate the XStream with PureJavaReflectionProvider, using Pure Java.

the following error occurs in the same JVM:

```
 com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.ConversionException: Cannot construct java.util.TreeMap$KeySet as it does not have a no-args constructor : Cannot construct java.util.TreeMap$KeySet as it does not have a no-args constructor
---- Debugging information ----
message             : Cannot construct java.util.TreeMap$KeySet as it does not have a no-args constructor
cause-exception     : com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.reflection.ObjectAccessException
cause-message       : Cannot construct java.util.TreeMap$KeySet as it does not have a no-args constructor
class               : java.util.TreeMap$KeySet
required-type       : java.util.TreeMap$KeySet
converter-type      : com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.reflection.ReflectionConverter
path                : /map/entry[93]/java.util.TreeMap$KeySet
line number         : 36154
class[1]            : java.util.HashMap
converter-type[1]   : com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.collections.MapConverter
version             : null
-------------------------------
```

Answer (score 0):

I'll start by answering your first question:

> Why it generate this for TreeMaps?

The element local name is `java.util.TreeMap_-1` because XStream attempted to serialize an anonymous inner class of `java.util.TreeMap`.

As for the second question:

> How can i write a generic collections types into this output xml, that can be assembled into different jdks?

You need to post more complete code to demonstrate the problem.  Please see [SSCCE.org](https://sscce.org/) to understand what code is necessary.  As it stands, you have not provided a sufficient example for someone else to reproduce the problem.

I'll make some educated guesses about the problem based on what you've provided.

Out of the box, XStream provides [a number of converters](http://xstream.codehaus.org/converters.html), including `TreeMapConverter` for `java.util.TreeMap`.  When I run XStream's serialization against a TreeMap in my environment, I do not see either the `KeySet` inner class, nor an anonymous inner class being serialized:

```
import com.thoughtworks.xstream.XStream;
import com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.MapperWrapper;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.TreeMap;

public class App {

    public static XStream getXStreamConfigured() {

        final XStream xstream = new XStream() {

            @Override
            protected MapperWrapper wrapMapper(final MapperWrapper next) {

                return new MapperWrapper(next) {

                    @Override
                    public boolean shouldSerializeMember(
                            final Class definedIn,
                            final String fieldName) {

                        if (definedIn == Object.class) {
                            return false;
                        }

                        return super.shouldSerializeMember(definedIn, fieldName);
                    }

                };
            }

        };

        xstream.autodetectAnnotations(true);

        return xstream;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        XStream xs = getXStreamConfigured();

        xs.toXML(new ExampleContainer().fill(), System.out);
    }

    public static class ExampleContainer {

        private TreeMap<String, Date> map = new TreeMap<>();

        public ExampleContainer() {
        }

        public ExampleContainer fill() {

            map.put("a", new Date());
            map.put("b", new Date());
            map.put("c", new Date());
            map.put("d", new Date());
            return this;
        }
    }
}
```

That code gives me the following output:

```
<App_-ExampleContainer>
  <map>
    <entry>
      <string>a</string>
      <date>2014-06-21 22:40:53.598 UTC</date>
    </entry>
    <entry>
      <string>b</string>
      <date>2014-06-21 22:40:53.598 UTC</date>
    </entry>
    <entry>
      <string>c</string>
      <date>2014-06-21 22:40:53.598 UTC</date>
    </entry>
    <entry>
      <string>d</string>
      <date>2014-06-21 22:40:53.598 UTC</date>
    </entry>
  </map>
</App_-ExampleContainer>
```

That seems to suggest to me that XStream is using its default converter(s), which use reflection to inspect a class's members for `TreeMap`.  Some possible reasons why this can occur includes incorrect modification of the `MapperWrapper`, or registration of an incorrect `Converter`.

For a better analysis, please provide an SSCCE demonstrating your problem.

Comment: Ok. 
Thank you for the reply. I gonna provide the SSCCE.

To reproduce this problem we need 2 diferents jdk installed. In my case i use ibm jdk 1.6(IBM-Java60-amd64) to serialize into xml and oracle jdk 1.6(orecle-jdk1.6.0-x86) to construct the collection again.

Comment: In each jdk, this serialization is different when its write the xml.
In oracle jdk, the output tag 4 TreeMap is diferent.

So i want to generete a xml that can be assembled in both jdks.
I edited the question.

Comment: i am serializing a httpSession map. This session map contains some TreeMap values, that i dont know where or how this is created in session, and i dont know who is using that.

Comment: Again, you should provide an SSCCE in order to diagnose the problem.  You don't have enough code in your question to even begin to compile, so it fails the "Correct" test of the SSCCE.  It isn't self-contained, either, as evidenced by what you just said -- the problem is in an `HttpSession` map.  By reproducing the problem in a short, self-contained, correct example ("SSCCE"), you make it much more likely that your problem gets examined and solved, demonstrating that you've actually tried to solve it yourself.

Comment: I gonna provide the SSCCE. Give me some time to do this.

Comment: Sorry to not provide the SSCCEE. This project is a legacy code with lot of crazy stuff =(. So i basically worked only on my XStream object.

Comment: To generate a Session like that is gonna be really painfull.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution for my problem.

First I had to remove all the anonymous inner classes, and put that code fragment in a public class.
For example, I moved each single anonymous Comparator into a specific Comparator class. This also improved the design.

I needed to write a MapConverter, a CollectionConverter and a ComparatorConverter,  to serialize and assemble the objects appropriately.
This classes extend MapConverter, CollectionConverter and JavaBeanConverter which the XStream API provides.

I have created a static String ForbiddenClassesList that contains all specific classnames that a determinated jdk implements. For example, my list has:

`Collections.EMPTY_LIST.getClass()`

`Collections.singletonList( null ).getClass()`

In these cases, I had simply ignored, and serialized a really empty collection - `new ArrayList()`, in the marshal method execution.

I also tested the source class names against a list like:

`{"java.util.TreeMap$KeySet","java.util.TreeMap$1"}`

in my CollectionConverter, to not convert and redirect the object to the right Converter, such as my MapConverter.

After that, all is working fine! =)

Avoid all anonymous class and implement specific classes in cases like these.